# iOS - What do we call the type of menu which pops up, as seen when highlighting text

Tags: ios

When you highlight text in iOS, a menu is shown giving options such as cut and copy, it floats above the text and is black. What is this called and how can i implement it in a tableview (to give options when a row is selected)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this, this is a UIMenuController

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIMenuController_Class/

another bit of info:

http://nshipster.com/uimenucontroller/

How to use it:

https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/getting-started-with-uimenucontroller-in-ios-5

An actual example already coded up for you:

https://github.com/jszumski/uimenucontroller-example

Answer (score 1):

It is called [UIMenuController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIMenuController_Class/).

This menu is referred to as the editing menu. When you make this menu visible, UIMenuController positions it relative to a target rectangle on the screen; this rectangle usually defines a selection. The menu appears above the target rectangle or, if there is not enough space for it, below it.

You can also provide your own menu items via the [menuItems](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIMenuController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIMenuController/menuItems) property. When you modify the menu items, you can use the update method to force the menu to update its display.